# Outlook mailitem method SaveAs using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to save email drafts in a dedicated folder.

In display option (when I turn off SaveAs) it works.

I found this [on Microsoft Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas).

I receive an error (occurs on SaveAs line):

[image]

```vb
Sub t1()
            
    Dim appOutlook As Object
    Dim mItem As Object
                                    
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mItem = appOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        
    With mItem
        .To = "@"
        .Subject = "test1"
        .HTMLBody = "<html><p>TestTest</p></html>"
        .SaveAs "myCorrectPathHere\test1.msg", OlSaveAsType.olMsg
        '.display
    End With
            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that since you're using late-binding you didn't set a reference to Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object library. Which likely means that your Excel IDE has no clue as to what `OlSaveAsType` is. You should either early bind Outlook or use the numeric value of the `OlSaveAsType.olMsg` constant, which is `3`.

```
.SaveAs "myCorrectPathHere\test1.msg", 3
```

If you're looking to Early Bind your Outlook objects, which is recommended for a variety of reasons, you should go to **Tools > References** and then check the box next to your

```
Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library
```

[image]

Once you've done that, you can then change your code to use early binding, which means no more generic `As Object` variables or using `CreateObject()`...

```
Sub t1()

    Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set appOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Set mItem = appOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    With mItem
        .To = "@"
        .Subject = "test1"
        .HTMLBody = "<html><p>TestTest</p></html>"
        .SaveAs "myCorrectPathHere\test1.msg", OlSaveAsType.olMSG
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

---

## Edit

You should get in the habit of using `Option Explicit` at the top of every code module in the IDE, which requires all variables to be explicitly declared.

The Outlook COM library that you would have referenced already defines what this is, which is why you aren't required to do so when you set the reference to it.

But this would have given you a compile error letting you know that `OlSaveAsType` isn't defined.

Comment: I tried the first solution and it didn't work, I checked out the early binding now, but it did not work out either. I get the same error.

Comment: Have you verified the file path is correct - and that you have write permissions to that path? Maybe try a different path for testing first. I just tested my code in Excel after setting object references and it works just fine, so your issue may be deeper than what the code itself is.

Comment: I changed the command to save and it works fine, so it might be that this is a permission problem. However I checked even on simplest pths I am sure I have right to edit.